# Using Halide ahead-of-time (AOT) with Metal on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, halide

I'm trying to use Metal as the target for my ahead-of-time (AOT) Halide pipeline for use on iOS.

I've successfully created a Halide generator that generates a static binary using Metal. I can link and call this binary in my iOS app.

However, when I pass an `Buffer<uint8_t> input_` to the function, the data in the `Buffer` always seems to be zero on the GPU side. Note that this only happens when running on the GPU on iOS.

**Generator**

```
#include "Halide.h"

using namespace Halide;

class MyHalideTest : public Halide::Generator<MyHalideTest> {
public:
    Input<Buffer<uint8_t>> input{"input", 3};
    Input<int32_t> width{"width"};
    Input<int32_t> height{"height"};
    Output<Buffer<uint8_t>> output{"output", 3};

    void generate() {
        output(x,y,c) = cast<uint8_t>(input(x,y,c)+25);
    }

    void schedule() {
        input
            .dim(0).set_stride(4)
            .dim(2).set_stride(1).set_bounds(0, 4);
        output
            .dim(0).set_stride(4)
            .dim(2).set_stride(1).set_bounds(0, 4);

        if (get_target().has_gpu_feature()) {
            output
                .reorder(c, x, y)
                .bound(c, 0, 4)
                .unroll(c);
            output.gpu_tile(x, y, xo, yo, xi, yi, 16, 16);
        }
        else {
            output
                .reorder(c, x, y)
                .unroll(c)
                .split(y, yo, yi, 16)
                .parallel(yo)
                .vectorize(x, 8);
        }
    }

private:
    Var x{"x"}, y{"y"}, c{"c"}, xi{"xi"}, xo{"xo"}, yi{"yi"}, yo{"yo"};

};

HALIDE_REGISTER_GENERATOR(MyHalideTest, "halide_test")
```

**Command line to generate Generator**

```
./MyHalideTest_generator -g halide_test \
-f halide_test_ARM64_metal \
-n halide_test_ARM64_metal \
-o "${DERIVED_FILE_DIR}" \
target=arm-64-ios-metal-debug-user_context
```

**iOS code calling Halide function**

```
Buffer<uint8_t> input_;
Buffer<uint8_t> output_;

// Other setup

- (void)initBuffersWithWidth:(int)w height:(int)h using_metal:(bool)using_metal
{
    // We really only need to pad this for the use_metal case,
    // but it doesn't really hurt to always do it.
    const int c = 4;
    const int pad_pixels = (64 / sizeof(int32_t));
    const int row_stride = (w + pad_pixels - 1) & ~(pad_pixels - 1);
    const halide_dimension_t pixelBufShape[] = {
        {0, w, c},
        {0, h, c * row_stride},
        {0, c, 1}
    };

    input_ = Buffer<uint8_t>(nullptr, 3, pixelBufShape);
    input_.allocate();
    auto buf = input_.raw_buffer()->host;
    memset(buf, 200, input_.size_in_bytes());

    // This allows us to make a Buffer with an arbitrary shape
    // and memory managed by Buffer itself
    output_ = Buffer<uint8_t>(nullptr, 3, pixelBufShape);
    output_.allocate();
}

...

/** Calling Halide function here **/
halide_test((__bridge void *)self, input_, width, height, output_);
output_.copy_to_host();

// Display output image...
```

So, the code sets the `input_` buffer to be values of 200. The returned `output_` buffer should be 225, but it's not. All the values are only 25.

I should note that this works *correctly* when running on my laptop's GPU and on the phone's CPU. The only difference is the Halide generator `target`.

Any ideas on why the `Input<Buffer<uint8_t>> input` seems to be set to all zeros when running the Halide function?

The debug statements seem to malloc memory on the device side, but I don't see an explicit statement saying `halide_copy_to_device`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set values in a `Buffer`, you need to mark it dirty: `input_.set_host_dirty()`